# I need help getting aggregated data from mongodb - some in arrays and some not in arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of records that look like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("bbbbbb1d9486c90479aaaaaa"),
    "record" : {
        "type" : "MX_GTI",
        "products" : [ 
            "DAM"
        ],
        "services" : [ 
            "MySQL", 
            "DB2", 
            "MSSQL"
        ],
        "agents" : [ 
            {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw01",
                "agentId" : 10140,
                "hpsAvg" : 772,
                "hpsMax" : 42901,
                "services" : "mssql"
            }, 
            {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw01",
                "agentId" : 10120,
                "hpsAvg" : 95,
                "hpsMax" : 21631,
                "services" : "mssql"
            }, 
            {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw02",
                "agentId" : 10187,
                "hpsAvg" : 0,
                "hpsMax" : 0,
                "services" : "mssql"
            }, 
            {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw03",
                "agentId" : 10213,
                "hpsAvg" : 0,
                "hpsMax" : 0,
                "services" : "db2"
            }
        ],
        "gateways" : {
            "impDBFgw01" : {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw01",
                "avgHps" : 875,
                "maxHps" : 15474
            },
            "impDBFgw02" : {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw02",
                "avgHps" : 0,
                "maxHps" : 0
            },
            "impDBFgw03" : {
                "gatewayName" : "impDBFgw03",
                "avgHps" : 2892,
                "maxHps" : 76009
            }
        },
        "debug" : false
    }
}
```

I need help with two queries:

1. For all records with `type MX_GTI` and `products` that include `DAM`, get the fields `services`, `hpsAvg` and `hpsMax` for each agent in the `agents[]` array as a string in the format `<services>/<hpsAvg>/<hpsMax>`. Note - the services may be an array.
2. For the same records, get the number of gateways (number of elements in the `gateways` object). It's not an array and I can't change that.

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this solution meets your requirements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "record.type": "MX_GTI",
      "record.products": "DAM"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      num_gateway: {
        $size: {
          $objectToArray: "$record.gateways"
        }
      },
      agents: {
        $map: {
          input: "$record.agents",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $isArray: "$$this.services"
                  },
                  {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: "$$this.services",
                      initialValue: "",
                      in: {
                        $concat: [
                          "$$value",
                          "$$this",
                          ","
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "$$this.services"
                ]
              },
              "/",
              {
                $toString: "$$this.hpsAvg"
              },
              "/",
              {
                $toString: "$$this.hpsMax"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CcJzY42FVDI)

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. I need to tweak it a little because my MongoDB server is before 4.0 so it doesn't have all the functions, but in principle you've put me on the right way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It turns out that I need the agents not as concatenated strings but as separate fields. So for each agent I need a record with the fields ```agentId```, ```services```, ```hpsAvg``` and ```apsMax```. Can you help me here too? Thank you.

Comment: @Shimon post please desired result, it's more easier for me :)

Comment: Sorry, this new question was stupid of me. It's just a selection of fields. But thanks a lot for your help. I am a raw beginner in MongoDB. I have trouble adjusting to the paradigm.

Comment: I need help with one more query: go over all the agents in all the documents in the database, and extract the Max and Average for each ```service```. That is, get the largest ```hpsMax``` and the average of all non-zero ```hpsAvg``` for each ```service``` separately (mssql, db2, oracle, etc.). So the output of this query should be an array with elements that are triplets: ```[ {"service": <service>, "max": <max for the service>, "average": <average of non-zeros for this service>}, ...]```

Comment: @Shimon why don't you mark this answer?  You are asking quetions, getting answers. but don't mark them as answer.

Comment: Because I didn't know what the tick mark meant until now. Thanks for pointing it out.